# "No such file or directory" running an ELF executable that certainly exists

Tags: bash

I have a `bank2` file but I don't know why I can't run it.

```
geordo@ExpMachine:~/CTF/HCMUS/2021-Quals/pwn-bank2$ ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 geordo geordo 4096 Oct 26 22:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 geordo geordo 4096 Oct 26 22:09 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 geordo geordo 9988 Jul  4 18:20 bank2
geordo@ExpMachine:~/CTF/HCMUS/2021-Quals/pwn-bank2$ file bank2
bank2: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=5a9d499a78c78d9af814ff6464cf63656165299b, with debug_info, not stripped
geordo@ExpMachine:~/CTF/HCMUS/2021-Quals/pwn-bank2$ ./bank2
-bash: ./bank2: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you check it's a bash file? Check if the extension is `.sh`

Comment: @xXJohnRamboXx, shell scripts are not supposed to have extensions; it's bad form. See [Commandname Extensions Considered Harmful](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/) -- you run `ls`, not `ls.elf`, and `pip`, not `pip.py`; similarly, executables written in shell should have no extension.

Comment: @GeorgeDo., use `ldd bank2` to check the shared libraries your executable tries to link. And, err, _is_ this in fact a 32-bit machine (or a machine with 32-bit compatibility tooling installed)? If you only have 64-bit libraries and a 64-bit ld.so, running a 32-bit executable is going to be a problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I checked and get not a dynamic executable

Comment: That's not what `file` says -- `file` very explicitly says it's dynamically linked. What does `/lib/ld-linux.so.2 ./bank2` say?

Comment: The next place I might go is inspecting dependencies with `objdump`.

Comment: (...that said, you could also `strace /lib/ld-linux.so.2 ./bank2` and see exactly which files ld-linux.so.2 is trying and failing to find; of course, if you don't _have_ a `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` -- as can happen on some oddball distros, including [one I personally use](https://nixos.org/) -- that's a completely different and much clearer problem).

Comment: I get `./bank2: error while loading shared libraries: ./bank2: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32`

Comment: See again re: question as to whether your system is actually 32-bit compatible.

Comment: @GeorgeDo., ...which distro are you running, and which specific version of that distro? (And just to confirm, you're on an Intel-compatible architecture?) -- if we know, we can look up what the 32-bit compatibility package is, if there is one. And which specific distro was your executable compiled for?

Comment: (mind, problems running something you didn't compile is arguably more a [unix.se] question than one on-topic here).

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy. My WSL2 system isn't compatible with 32-bit. I solved it by installing `gcc-multilib`.

Comment: Next time, include pertinent environment details -- like use of WSL -- up-front.